# RestKit Derived Data Troubles

Tags: ios

I'm trying to get going with Restkit. I've followed the install instructions here: https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Installing-RestKit-in-Xcode-4.x

I'm running Xcode 4.3.2. When I try to run the RKCatalog project, I get an error: clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/sparky/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RKCatalog-fdohdnazcupmydfaxxedezitkbpl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RestKit/RestKit'

I'm not an Xcode expert. I'm not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 9):

If you have `Restkit.framework` added in the libraries in "Build Phases" (Targets > Build Phases > Link Binary With Libraries) **you have to remove it**. I learnt from one of the discussions on GitHub that `Restkit.framework` is for Mac OSX and `libRestKit.a` is for iOS.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue with my project. What worked for me was to delete all reference to my project on the DerivedData folder. So, in your case:

```
rm -rf /Users/sparky/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RKCatalog-*
```

After this, try restarting XCode.

Comment: This helped me troubleshoot an issue with a file not found in my derived data

Answer (score 0):

You can easily clear Xcode's derived data folder using the keyboard shortcut:

<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd>